# How to properly install eopen-ecd in WSL with Ubuntu distro

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've tried cloning eopen from this link https://github.com/ko1nksm/eopen-ecd into my local user directory and added this line of code: `eval "$(sh "/home/user/eopen-ecd/init.sh")"` into the `.bashrc` as instructed in the Installation guide. After resetting my wsl terminal, this following error is shown:

```
[eopen-ecd] ebridge.exe not found or is not executable.   
Place ebridge.exe and enter the following command.   
chmod +x '/home/user/eopen-ecd/bin/ebridge.exe'.
```

The error shows every new instance of the bash terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work! The instruction was in the error message all along...

```
...
Place ebridge.exe and enter the following command.
chmod +x 'home/user/eopen-ecd/bin/ebridge.exe'
```

Just follow the instructions above after downloading eopen-ecd from this [link](https://github.com/ko1nksm/eopen-ecd/releases) and viola! Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Download the archive containing `ebridge.exe` from [here](https://github.com/ko1nksm/eopen-ecd/releases) and place it in the appropriate path.

Comment: I downloaded the one with the `ebridge.exe` and changed the folder name to eopen-ecd to match the path I added to the `.bashrc` but the error still persists and the `eopen` wouldn't work.Yes, I downloaded the x64 one for my operating system and even tried the x86 to see if it works.